# Why does one these functions fail with a type error, while the other doesn't?

Tags: haskell

In GHCi, if I define two functions like so:

```
> let succ = (+ 1)
> let pred = (- 1)
```

And then call them both, like so:

```
> succ 5
> pred 5
```

Why does one (`succ`) run just fine, while the other fails with the following error?

```
<interactive>:3:1:
Could not deduce (Num (a0 -> t))
  arising from the ambiguity check for ‘it’
from the context (Num (a -> t), Num a)
  bound by the inferred type for ‘it’: (Num (a -> t), Num a) => t
  at <interactive>:3:1-6
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
When checking that ‘it’
  has the inferred type ‘forall a t. (Num (a -> t), Num a) => t’
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

What is causing the type inference to fail in one function and not the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-` has a weird special syntax rule in Haskell. It's the only infix that can't be used as a left-infix section, instead `-x` will always be parsed as a single negative number. The symbol is only recognised as an infix when

- used explicitly as subtraction, `2-1`
- used as a right section, `(1-)`
- used as a dyadic prefix function, `(-) 1`.

Comment: Huh. That does indeed seem to be what's happening. Thanks!

(Also, I just noticed that my current pointfree version of `pred` doesn't actually do what I want.)